# Using PHP, parse JSON response with values deeply nested?

Tags: php, html, json

I researched and researched and cannot find an answer. Below is a portion of a response I get back after making an API call.

```
{
"api_version":"0.4",
"results":
    {
    "companies":[
        {
            "company":
            {
            "name":"BILL, HILLARY \u0026 CHELSEA CLINTON FOUNDATION",
            "company_number":"EXTUID_4147727",
            "jurisdiction_code":"us_dc",
            "incorporation_date":"1997-10-23",
            "dissolution_date":"2014-11-20",
            "company_type":"Non-Profit Corporation",
            "registry_url":"https://corp.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=4147727",
            "branch":"F",
            "branch_status":"branch of an out-of-jurisdiction company",
            "inactive":true,
            "current_status":"Revoked",
            "created_at":"2015-12-04T13:32:35+00:00",
            "updated_at":"2018-01-16T16:14:02+00:00",
            "retrieved_at":"2016-03-14T00:40:43+00:00",
            "opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_dc/EXTUID_4147727",
            "previous_names":[],
            "source":
                {
                "publisher":"District of Columbia Department of Consumer and Regulatory Affairs",
                "url":"https://corp.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=4147727",
                "retrieved_at":"2016-03-14T00:40:43+00:00"},
                "registered_address":
                    {
                    "street_address":"1200 PRESIDENT CLINTON AVENUE,",
                    "locality":"LITTLE ROCK",
                    "region":"Arkansas",
                    "postal_code":"72201",
                    "country":"United States"
                    },
                "registered_address_in_full":"1200 PRESIDENT CLINTON AVENUE,, LITTLE ROCK, Arkansas, 72201",
                "industry_codes":[],
                "restricted_for_marketing":null,
                "native_company_number":"N00005066161"
                }
            },
        {
            "company":
            {
            "name":"BILL, HILLARY \u0026 CHELSEA CLINTON FOUNDATION",
            "company_number":"EXTUID_2698590",
            "jurisdiction_code":"us_dc",
            "incorporation_date":"2016-03-03",
            "dissolution_date":null,
            "company_type":"Non-Profit Corporation",
            "registry_url":"https://corponline.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=2698590",
            "branch":"F",
            "branch_status":"branch of an out-of-jurisdiction company",
            "inactive":false,
            "current_status":"Active",
            "created_at":"2015-12-08T12:22:52+00:00",
            "updated_at":"2020-04-19T21:38:13+00:00",
            "retrieved_at":"2020-04-19T17:55:36+00:00",
            "opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_dc/EXTUID_2698590",
            "previous_names":[],
            "source":
                {
                "publisher":"District of Columbia Department of Consumer and Regulatory Affairs",
                "url":"https://corponline.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=2698590",
                "retrieved_at":"2020-04-19T17:55:36+00:00"},
                "registered_address":
                    {
                    "street_address":"1200 President Clinton Avenue,",
                    "locality":"LITTLE ROCK",
                    "region":"Arkansas",
                    "postal_code":"72201",
                    "country":"United States"
                    },
                "registered_address_in_full":"1200 President Clinton Avenue,, LITTLE ROCK, Arkansas, 72201",
                "industry_codes":[],
                "restricted_for_marketing":null,
                "native_company_number":"292233"
                }
            }
```

Below is my PHP where I am attempting to retrieve, parse and display the JSON Response.

```
        <?php
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q=".$googleSearchTerm);
    $json =  json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $output = "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Incorporation Date</th>
            <th>Dissolution Date</th>
            <th>Company Type</th>                   
            <th>Registry URL</th>
            <th>Current Status</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    
    ";
    foreach($json['results']['companies']['company'] as $company){
        $output .= "<tr>";
        $output .= "<td>".$company['name']."<td>";
        $output .= "<td>".$company['incorporation_date']."<td>";
        $output .= "<td>".$company['dissolution_date']."<td>";
        $output .= "<td>".$company['company_type']."<td>";
        $output .= "<td><a href='".$company['registry_url']."'></a>Registry Link<td>";
        $output .= "<td>".$company['current_status']."<td>";
        $output .= "<td>".$company['registered_address_in_full']."<td>";
    }
    $output .= "</tr></table>";
    echo $output;


    ?>
```

Below are the two errors I receive trying to parse this.

> Notice: Undefined index: company in /opt/lampp/htdocs/OSINTTools.php on line 433
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/OSINTTools.php on line 433

I think I am getting these errors because I am not accessing the values correctly. Can someone show me the correct syntax for accessing the values deeply nested in this JSON Response. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know this question has been asked before. I have used the beautiful search tool to find similar problems as mine to no avail.

Comment: `foreach($json['results']['companies']['company'] as $company){` Looks like you went one level too deep there

Comment: I don't think this is going to work as an associative array, because it re-uses the "company" index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results reuses the index "company" so that's going to confuse the whole thing if you try to go straight to it.  I've tested the following, and it works:  PROVIDED that the rest of that string is closed up with the missing brackets.

```
$string = '{
"api_version":"0.4",
"results":
    {
    "companies":[
        {
            "company":
            {
            "name":"BILL, HILLARY \u0026 CHELSEA CLINTON FOUNDATION",
            "company_number":"EXTUID_4147727",
            "jurisdiction_code":"us_dc",
            "incorporation_date":"1997-10-23",
            "dissolution_date":"2014-11-20",
            "company_type":"Non-Profit Corporation",
            "registry_url":"https://corp.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=4147727",
            "branch":"F",
            "branch_status":"branch of an out-of-jurisdiction company",
            "inactive":true,
            "current_status":"Revoked",
            "created_at":"2015-12-04T13:32:35+00:00",
            "updated_at":"2018-01-16T16:14:02+00:00",
            "retrieved_at":"2016-03-14T00:40:43+00:00",
            "opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_dc/EXTUID_4147727",
            "previous_names":[],
            "source":
                {
                "publisher":"District of Columbia Department of Consumer and Regulatory Affairs",
                "url":"https://corp.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=4147727",
                "retrieved_at":"2016-03-14T00:40:43+00:00"},
                "registered_address":
                    {
                    "street_address":"1200 PRESIDENT CLINTON AVENUE,",
                    "locality":"LITTLE ROCK",
                    "region":"Arkansas",
                    "postal_code":"72201",
                    "country":"United States"
                    },
                "registered_address_in_full":"1200 PRESIDENT CLINTON AVENUE,, LITTLE ROCK, Arkansas, 72201",
                "industry_codes":[],
                "restricted_for_marketing":null,
                "native_company_number":"N00005066161"
                }
            },
        {
            "company":
            {
            "name":"BILL, HILLARY \u0026 CHELSEA CLINTON FOUNDATION",
            "company_number":"EXTUID_2698590",
            "jurisdiction_code":"us_dc",
            "incorporation_date":"2016-03-03",
            "dissolution_date":null,
            "company_type":"Non-Profit Corporation",
            "registry_url":"https://corponline.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=2698590",
            "branch":"F",
            "branch_status":"branch of an out-of-jurisdiction company",
            "inactive":false,
            "current_status":"Active",
            "created_at":"2015-12-08T12:22:52+00:00",
            "updated_at":"2020-04-19T21:38:13+00:00",
            "retrieved_at":"2020-04-19T17:55:36+00:00",
            "opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_dc/EXTUID_2698590",
            "previous_names":[],
            "source":
                {
                "publisher":"District of Columbia Department of Consumer and Regulatory Affairs",
                "url":"https://corponline.dcra.dc.gov/BizEntity.aspx/ViewEntityData?entityId=2698590",
                "retrieved_at":"2020-04-19T17:55:36+00:00"},
                "registered_address":
                    {
                    "street_address":"1200 President Clinton Avenue,",
                    "locality":"LITTLE ROCK",
                    "region":"Arkansas",
                    "postal_code":"72201",
                    "country":"United States"
                    },
                "registered_address_in_full":"1200 President Clinton Avenue,, LITTLE ROCK, Arkansas, 72201",
                "industry_codes":[],
                "restricted_for_marketing":null,
                "native_company_number":"292233"
                }
            }]}}';                              //missing brackets are added here
```

...

```
$json =  json_decode($string);
$companies = $json->results->companies;

$output = "
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Incorporation Date</th>
        <th>Dissolution Date</th>
        <th>Company Type</th>                   
        <th>Registry URL</th>
        <th>Current Status</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>

";


foreach($companies as $company){
    foreach($company as $data){

    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .= "<td>".$data->name."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$data->incorporation_date."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$data->dissolution_date."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$data->company_type."<td>";
    $output .= "<td><a href='".$data->registry_url."'></a>Registry Link<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$data->current_status."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$data->registered_address_in_full."<td>";

}
}
$output .= "</tr></table>";
echo $output;
```

Comment: I ran this code exactly as I entered it here and it worked for me.  Maybe try copying this code and running it separately, just to make sure it behaves the same way on your machine, thereby removing the variable of whatever else you did with it.  After that, I wonder what the rest of your results string looks like, because it looks like you cut off the rest of it (missing the final brackets).  What else did you cut off?

Comment: I did exactly what you said. I get the following errors. 
`Trying to get property 'results' of non-object
Trying to get property 'companies' of non-object`
I'm not sure if I was clear earlier, but I am pulling the JSON string from a URL. Does this matter in the code provided? or can I simple replace $string with the URL?

Comment: Sorry, I missed 'file_get_contents. I got it working! You are the man, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your second error is because of your first error. Your first error is because you are trying to loop one level too deep in your data.

Try this:

```
foreach($json['results']['companies'] as $company_values){

    $company = $company_values['company'];

    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .= "<td>".$company['name']."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$company['incorporation_date']."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$company['dissolution_date']."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$company['company_type']."<td>";
    $output .= "<td><a href='".$company['registry_url']."'></a>Registry Link<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$company['current_status']."<td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$company['registered_address_in_full']."<td>";
}
```

Basically, your loop needs to start 1 level higher, and inside the loop you can pull the values from the `company` key.

Comment: Now I get 
`Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.opencorporates.com/v0.4/companies/search?q=Jack+Kwaak): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /opt/lampp/htdocs/OSINTTools.php on line 418`

Comment: @JackK. I don't know why you are getting that, it's an issue with your `file_get_contents()` which I didn't touch in my code at all.

Comment: Its weird, Its a public API and doesnt require an API Key. So strange. Thanks for your help. Its got me a lot closer.

Comment: @JackK. No problem, glad that I could help. The API could have just gone down for a sec and couldn't authenticate the request for some reason

Comment: They are limiting the number of API calls I can make. Because I was troubleshooting evidently I exceeded the number of calls I can make. Not sure how they are tracking that from me. I provide no identifiers.

Comment: @JackK. Interesting. I'm not sure either, maybe by IP somehow or maybe tracking it based on how many calls have your site as referer.

Comment: Ok so the API Calls reset and I ran the program with your code. Everything seems fine except I am getting this error now. Any thoughts?

`Trying to get property 'results' of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/OSINTTools.php on line 397`